# No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer, nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While creating new Student Im getting error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

In Students Controller,

```
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:name, :lastname, :subjects_attributes [:id, :name :_destroy, :mark_attributes [ :id, :value ]] )
end
```

What causes this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
:subjects_attributes [:id, :name :_destroy, :mark_attributes [ :id, :value ]] )
```

You should have a colon(`:`) after `subject_attributes`, not before it.

You can do either `:subject_attributes => [:id, :name, :_destroy...]` or `subject_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy...]`

The syntax without `=>` is used with Ruby 2.0+, and is preferred one.

Answer (score 2):

Bilal is correct. **Also**, you'll have to change `:mark_attributes` to `mark_attributes:`.

Why?

`:subjects_attributes` is a [`symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html). But `subjects_attributes: [ ]` is a [`hash`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) where the `key` is `:subjects_attributes` (a `symbol`, as it turns out) and the value is `[ ]`.

So, strong parameters knows how to process the `hash` defined by `subjects_attributes: [ ]` just fine.

But a symbol followed by an array, like `:subjects_attributes [ ]`? Well, that makes for all kinds of unhappiness accompanied by falling on the floor, kicking, and screaming.

As Bilal also points out, you can get back to a place of happiness by doing `:subjects_attributes => [ ]`, which also creates hash and makes the sun shine again.

And **that**, my friend, is the answer to the question "What causes this problem?"